# How to get the year number with PHP?

Tags: php, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I use PHP to get the current year?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64003/how-do-i-use-php-to-get-the-current-year)

2009 this year,
2010 next year.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64003/how-do-i-use-php-to-get-the-current-year

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Look at the functions date() and strtotime():

```
echo date('Y');
echo date('Y', strtotime('+1 year'));
```

Answer (score 18):

You can use the date function to extract a part of a date:

```
$year = date("Y"); // get the year part of the current date
$nextYear = $year + 1;
```

Run the snippet [here](http://codepad.org/LCpndEBL).

Answer (score 13):

```
<?php
$date="2010-04-30";
$y = date('Y',strtotime($date));
echo $y; 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [getdate()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_getdate.asp) function

Answer (score 1):

...and `strftime('%Y')` does it too