# PHP date actual year

Tags: php

I have this:

```
$startdate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('2015-' . $startmonth . '-01'));
```

But instead of filling in the year, how do I get the current year?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64003/how-do-i-use-php-to-get-the-current-year

Comment: date("Y-m-d", strtotime( date('Y') . '-' . $startmonth . '-01'));

Comment: @DenisFrezatto that screws up my month and day

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `date('Y')`

```
$startdate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime(date('Y') . '-' . $startmonth . '-01'));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use date, since the year will remain a year. 
for instance,

```
<?php echo date("Y"); ?>
```

Personal experience in researching in Google.

Comment: @Denis Frezzato already comment out the link for the answer, and he want  month and day as well