# Bootstrap yearly number auto increment

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Is there a way in which you can auto increment a number each year.

For example:
You have a business that started in 2010 and you have a line on the site that says "we have 11 years of experience" (as of 2021).

Is there a way to auto increment that number to 12 years when we go into 2022?

Comment: you can use [PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64003/how-do-i-use-php-to-get-the-current-year) or [JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002254/get-the-current-year-in-javascript) to get the current year, and then subtract 2010 from current year value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap doesn't offer this feature, but you can do something similar to this using javascript:

```html
we have
<script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear() - 2010)</script>
years of experience
```

Comment: You can remove the `Date.now()` since it `new Date()` would take current date by default. The statement can be written as `document.write( (new Date()).getFullYear()) - 2010)`